# how to handle or enforce data access security on every rest subpath?

Tags: rest, http, security, spring-security, user-permissions

My web app is secured with Spring Security and has a Rest API like:

```
GET /assets

GET /assets/<assetId>

GET /assets/<assetId>/parts

...

GET /assets/<assetId>/parts/<partId>/blueprints/<blueId>/print
```

and several others.

Each authenticated user may access a subset of all the available assets, i.e. Alice may see asset id 1 while Bob can see only assetId's 2 and 3.

So when doing:

```
GET /assets
```

Alice receives `[1]`, while Bob `[2, 3]`.

Consequently, Alice is only allowed to do

```
GET /assets/1
```

And I would check that by querying the associations between users and assets; so far so good.

But the same holds when Alice does:

```
GET /assets/1/parts

GET /assets/1/parts/10/blueprints/1/print
```

In both requests I should check if Alice can access asset id `1`, plus any other condition may there be restrictions on *parts* and / or *blueprints*.

What is the correct way to check user data access permission in every method? Do I have to redo the same user checks in each method, adding the specific ones at the end?

I mean, inside the controller method behind each endpoint:

- `GET /assets/1`

  - check that user can see asset 1
- `GET /assets/1/parts/2/`

  - check that user can see asset 1
  - check that user can see part 2
- `GET /assets/1/parts/2/blueprints/3`

  - check that user can see asset 1
  - check that user can see part 2
  - check that user can see blueprint 3

Or is there any way to ensure that the check on `/assets/1` is done for every subpath starting from it?

Comment: Are you currently doing that inside the method?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai That's the first naïf approach that came to mind, I hope there are better ways though.

Answer (score 0):

- You should check the `@PreAuthorize` annotation and it is very powerful. You can even create a service and call it inside `@PreAuthorize` using `Spel`. You can combine multiple calls.
- For example you can create a service `accessCheckService` with methods like `checkUserAccesstoAsset(String userid, String assetId)`, and another method for `partId`
- Then you can call that service method inside the `@PreAuthorize` like @accessChecker.check(principal, #assetId), where `assetId` is a parameter for the method

  - https://www.mscharhag.com/grails/spring-security-call-bean-method-in-spel-expression
  - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#method-security-expressions
- If it is only GET request, you should check `@PostAuthorize` option as well. Because it can decide whether to return the retrieved  object